# jQuery AJAX return the function as data upon success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have codeigniter flashdata + jQuery AJAX call to show it. the code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

var res_no = '<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('res_no'); ?>';
var res_new = '<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('res_new'); ?>';

(function( $ ) {

$("#check-reservations").click(function() {

   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mycontroller/function",
            async: true,
            data: {
            res_no: res_no,
            res_new: res_new
            },
            success: function(data) {   
            if(data) {
            alert(data);
            }
           }
        });
     });

/*
Default Notifications
*/
$('#check-reservations').show(function() {

    if (res_no) {
    new PNotify({
        title: 'Hmm no new Reservations..',
        text: res_no,
        type: 'custom',
        addclass: 'notification-primary',
        icon: 'fa fa-info-circle '
    });
    }

    else if (res_new) {
    new PNotify({
        title: 'There\'s something new!',
        text: res_new,
        type: 'custom',
        addclass: 'notification-success',
        icon: 'fa fa-check'
    });
    }
   });
   }).apply( this, [ jQuery ]);
 </script>
```

inside the $.ajax data, i have added both

```
res_no: res_no,
res_new: res_new
```

which are just strings with text, upon success I retrive back alert with text. I want to get back the

```
new PNotify({
        title: 'Hmm no new Reservations..',
        text: res_no,
        type: 'custom',
        addclass: 'notification-primary',
        icon: 'fa fa-info-circle '
    });
```

PHP:

```
 /**
    * @filtered_reservations
    * @index
    */
    $filtered_reservations = $this->filter_array($reservations);          
    if (count($filtered_reservations) > 0) {
    foreach ($filtered_reservations as $index => $reservation) {
    $this->db->insert('reservations', $reservation);   
    } // end foreach   
    return $this->session->set_flashdata('res_new', "Success ". count($filtered_reservations) ." Reservations were Inserted!"); 
    print "Success ". count($filtered_reservations) ." Reservations were Inserted!";
    print "Reservations: ". count($kigores_id) ." found on kigo!";
    } /* end if */


    /**
    * @filtered_reservations
    * equal to 0
    */
    elseif (count($filtered_reservations) === 0) {
    print "Sorry no new Reservations!";
    return $this->session->set_flashdata('res_no', 'Sorry no new Reservations!');
    //$this->ci_alerts->set('warning', "Sorry no new Reservations!");
    }

    } /* end reservations */
```

What should I write in the data? Only solution I found so far is the window.reload which will show me the notification like I want but with refresh..

Comment: ajax sending data to controller??

Comment: Requesting information from controller not sending ...

Comment: Whats your php file.

Comment: The PHP is fine I have added

Comment: `url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/mycontroller/function",` check now

Comment: everything is working. but instead of seeing the actual PNotify i see Alert... because I don't know what to put in AJAX success

Comment: after ajax sucess you need to show what??

Comment: I need to show

    new PNotify({
        title: 'Hmm no new Reservations..',
        text: res_no,
        type: 'custom',
        addclass: 'notification-primary',
        icon: 'fa fa-info-circle '
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for that to happen, you need to place this:

```
$('#check-reservations').show(function() {
    if (res_no) {
        new PNotify({
            title: 'Hmm no new Reservations..',
            text: res_no,
            type: 'custom',
            addclass: 'notification-primary',
            icon: 'fa fa-info-circle '
        });
    } else if (res_new) {
        new PNotify({
            title: 'There\'s something new!',
            text: res_new,
            type: 'custom',
            addclass: 'notification-success',
            icon: 'fa fa-check'
        });
    }
});
```

inside your AJAX `success` results, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mycontroller/function",
    async: true,
    data: {
        res_no: res_no,
        res_new: res_new
    },
    success: function(data) {   
        if(data) {
            $('#check-reservations').show(function() {
                if (res_no) {
                    new PNotify({
                        title: 'Hmm no new Reservations..',
                        text: res_no,
                        type: 'custom',
                        addclass: 'notification-primary',
                        icon: 'fa fa-info-circle '
                    });
                } else if (res_new) {
                    new PNotify({
                        title: 'There\'s something new!',
                        text: res_new,
                        type: 'custom',
                        addclass: 'notification-success',
                        icon: 'fa fa-check'
                    });     
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, however now each time when i click my function. it is giving back always the same result (res_no). when it should give back (res_new)

however if i do the following:

   data: {
        res_no: res_no,
        res_new: res_new
    },
    
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }

and click the button the alert will show up with the proper result!
what is wrong here?

Comment: well the reason you are getting the same results is because you need to plug in whatever you receive back from your AJAX request. I dont know what you are receiving back from your AJAX because you have not specified that, so I cant know that. Perhaps update your original post with the PHP in your controller (the one AJAX uses)

Comment: I get back a number, if the number is higher then 1 res_new will set the flashsesseion res_new and if the number is 0 res_no will happen. added more of the php.

Comment: it seems to me that your PHP is printing out strings, not numbers.. AJAX will only receive what your function prints or echoes. So in your AJAX results you have to catch these results and write your conditionals based on the strings. You can check whats in your `data` variable using `console.log`, do you know how to do that?

Comment: using console.log nothing happens! I was thinking that at my controller function i setted up 2 flash sessions. 1 res_no, 2 res_new
and in ajax it is written like:
if (res_no) do something else if (res_new) do something.
however it seems like i am not compring anything? or the controller does not give me back the numbers? $filtered_reservations is a number of the reservations, how can i pass this variable into my AJAX ? so i can use it to make the comparison? appreciate your time and help!

Comment: you just have to echo or print out whatever you want in your AJAX results. I can help you through Teamviewer if you like.

Comment: Oh that would be really nice from you!

Comment: How can I send you my Teamviewer connections ?

Comment: through here, your ID and passcode. Then you delete it once I connect

Comment: Thanks alot Diego for helping me over Teamviewer was a great lession for me.